# element within ranges and distance between two points

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, range, element

I have a 53534x3 matrix with x, y and z coordinates.
I want to find the element of matrix within ranges as follows:

```
% coordinate range;
x1(x<-25|x>0);
x2(x<0|x>25);
y1(y<-40|y>0);
y2(y<0|y>40);
z1(z<45|z>17);
z2(z<17|z>82);
```

and insert them into a new matrix, so that it become

```
point1=[x1, y1, z1];
point2=[x2, y2, z2];
```

I need to find the distance between the two points.

```
% define points;
xd=x2-x1;
yd=y2-y1;
zd=z2-z1;
Distance=sqrt(xd*xd+yd*yd+zd*zd);
```

Is loop preferrably efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need loop. MATLAB very efficiently works with vectors and matrices as whole.

If your matrix is `a`:

```
point1 = a( (a(:,1)<-25 | a(:,1)>0) & ...
            (a(:,2)<-40 | a(:,2)>0) & ...
            (a(:,3)< 45 | a(:,3)>17) ,:);

point2 = a( (a(:,1)< 0 | a(:,1)>25) & ...
            (a(:,2)< 0 | a(:,2)>40) & ...
            (a(:,3)<17 | a(:,3)>82) ,:);
```

If number of points in `point1` and `point2` is equal and you need distance between points in order they appear in the matrix, you can do:

```
xd = point2(:,1)-point1(:,1);
yd = point2(:,2)-point1(:,2);
zd = point2(:,3)-point1(:,3);
Distance=sqrt(xd.^2+yd.^2+zd.^2);
```

In general case if you need distances between all points in `point1` and `point2` you can use PDIST2 function:

```
Distance = pdist2(point1, point2, 'euclidean');
```

Comment: thanks. i've tried and it states that "Error using - Matrix dimensions must agree." and Error in (line 9)
xd = point2(:,1)-point1(:,1);. stated point1=33683x1 and point2=7585x1

Comment: i really appreciate your help :) point1<33683x1 double> and point2<7585x1 double>. I think that's where the function contains error.

Comment: In addition, I've post similar question here; http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6860/matlab-element-within-ranges-and-distance-between-two-points/6869?noredirect=1#6869. You may check out the responses.

Comment: Agh, found an error in matrix indexing to get `point1` and `point2`. Corrected.

Comment: I think what become the problem for matrix dimension is z1(z<45|z>0);
z2(z<0|z>82);. What i meant here was actually z is between 45 and 82. Am i correct?

Comment: No, the error was in my code, that points get only one dimension, not 3. You can try again now.